# Convert from hive style plot to draw axes paralelly

Tags: d3.js

Long story short. I need to display chart of target-source items and I found that d3.js can do the job. I spend already many hours to get something from there and I finished with using Hive Plot like this one:
https://bost.ocks.org/mike/hive/

But the problem is that I will have only one pair of items and I want to display nodes and corresponding to them items not in let's say circular manner but more conventional parallel (like in image below, left is actual result, right is desired one)[[image]
I tried many things but unfortunately i get lost.
I tried also get jsfiddle up and running but for unknown reason for me is not displaying anything. Here's the jsfiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/a7yrjfgc/2/
```

Code:

```
var width = 200,
    height = 200,
    innerRadius = 10,
    outerRadius = 100,
    majorAngle = 1 * Math.PI / 1,
    minorAngle = 1 * Math.PI / 2;

var angle = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(["source", "source-target", "target-source", "target"])
            .range([0, majorAngle - minorAngle, majorAngle + minorAngle, 2 * majorAngle]);
    radius = d3.scaleLinear()
              .range([innerRadius, outerRadius]),
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),
    formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

var nodes = [
  {x: 0, y: .4, name: "node1", color: "#0000FF"},
  {x: 0, y: .2, name: "node2", color: "#FFA500"},
  {x: 1, y: .2, name: "node3", color: "#008000"},
  {x: 1, y: .3, name: "node4", color: "#A52A2A"},
];

var links = [
  {source: nodes[0], target: nodes[2]},
  {source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3]},
];

var info = d3.select("#info")
        .text(defaultInfo = "Showing " + formatNumber(links.length) + " splices " + formatNumber(nodes.length) + "  strands.");
console.log(info);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

svg.selectAll(".axis")
    .data(d3.range(2))
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d)) + ")" })
    .attr("x1", radius.range()[0])
    .attr("x2", radius.range()[1]);

// draw links
svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", link()
    .angle(function(d) { return angle(d.x); })
    .radius(function(d) { return radius(d.y); }))
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.color); })
    .on("mouseover", linkMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);

// draw nodes
svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + degrees(angle(d.x)) + ")"; })
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return radius(d.y); })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d3.color(d.color); })
    .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Many, many thanks for helping in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

As i get to know more about how d3 works, I realized that I need to simply draw everything from scratch.

```
function DisplayGraph(){
  //D3 Configuration
  var width = 400,
  height = 50,
  color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10),
  formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
  defaultInfo ="";

var nodes = [
{x: 0, y: 0, name: "node1", color: "#0000FF"},
{x: 0, y: 15, name: "node2", color: "#FFA500"},
{x: 100, y: 15, name: "node3", color: "#008000"},
{x: 100, y: 0, name: "node4", color: "#A52A2A"},
];

var links = [
{source: nodes[0], target: nodes[2]},
{source: nodes[1], target: nodes[3]},
];

var info = d3.select("#info")
      .text(defaultInfo = "Showing " + formatNumber(links.length) + " splices " + formatNumber(nodes.length) + "  strands.");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + "," + height/2 + ")");

var diagonal = function link(d) {
  let sourceX = (d.source.x + 50);
  let sourceY = (d.source.y + 5);
  let targetX = (d.target.x);
  let targetY = (d.target.y + 5);

  var output =  "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY
      + "C" + (sourceX + targetX) / 2 + "," + sourceY
      + " " + (sourceX + targetX) / 2 + "," + targetY
      + " " + targetX + "," + targetY;
      return output;
  };

//draw squares
svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("width", 50)
.attr("height", 10)
.attr("x", function(d) {  return d.x; })
.attr("y", function(d) { return  d.y; })
.style("fill", function(d) { return d3.color(d.color); })
.on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
.on("mouseout", mouseout);

// draw links
svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", diagonal)
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.color); })
  .on("mouseover", linkMouseover)
  .on("mouseout", mouseout);

//Helpers
function linkMouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll(".link")
  .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl === d;
  })
  .classed("turnedOff", function(dl) {
      return !(dl === d);
  })
  svg.selectAll(".node")
  .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl === d.source || dl === d.target;
  })
  info.text(d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name);
  }
  // Highlight the node and connected links on mouseover.
function nodeMouseover(d) {
  svg.selectAll(".node")
  .classed("turnedOn", function(dl) {
      return dl.source === d || dl.target === d;
  })
  .classed("turnedOff", function(dl) {
      return !(dl.source === d || dl.target === d)
  });
  d3.select(this)
  .classed("turnedOn", true);
  info.text(d.name);
  }
  // Clear any highlighted nodes or links.
function mouseout() {
  svg.selectAll(".turnedOn").classed("turnedOn", false);
  svg.selectAll(".turnedOff").classed("turnedOff", false);
  info.text("Hover to node or link");
  }
}
```